# Open image in android Built-In Gallery only

Tags: android, image, gallery

i need to open an image in the built in gallery only, with no intent chooser.
if i use ACTION_VIEW, i automatically get the chooser.

is there any way to do this?

Tx,

Answer (score 3):

This opens the Gallery (not the picker). Tested on Android 2.3.3 on a Galacxy S

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Built-in gallery can be opened like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Intent.setClassName`? You could then specify the gallery intent and bypass the chooser entirely.

`final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gallery3d", "com.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery");
startActivity(intent);`

would start the  gallery application on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus Android 4.0 Jelly Bean. On a Samsung Galaxy S2, it's `"com.cooliris.media", "com.cooliris.media.Gallery"` instead. You would have to find out the class name for the specific phone, since it is different for any given phone.